# Issue getting desired input in credit card fraud machine learning project

Tags: r, machine-learning, project, dimensions, credit-card

Good evening, I'm currently working on a Credit Card Fraud Detection with Machine Learning project. Everything I did worked smoothly until I got to the data modeling section. The dimensions from train_data and test_data from the source differ from my version of the project.

Code from source:

```r
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
data_sample = sample.split(NewData$Class,SplitRatio=0.80)
train_data = subset(NewData,data_sample==TRUE)
test_data = subset(NewData,data_sample==FALSE)
```

My  code:

```r
    # Packages
library(ranger)
library(caret)
library(data.table)

    # Scaling  
credit.card.data$Amount = scale(credit.card.data$Amount)
new.data = credit.card.data[,-c(1)]
head(new.data)

    # Data modeling
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
data.sample = sample.split(new.data$Class, SplitRatio = 0.80)
train.data = subset(new.data, data.sample = T)
test.data = subset(new.data, data.sample = F)
```

Source output

[image]

My output

```r
> dim(train.data)
[1] 284807     30
> dim(test.data)
[1] 284807     30
```

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, the number of rows differ between train and test data, as expected. However, maybe you accidently used the same screenshot twice?

Comment: FYI, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189. I edited your question for: (1) basic code formatting; and (2) to remove all of the no-op expressions with no output (i.e., `dim`, `str`, `head`, etc), since they add no context to the question and unnecessarily lengthen code.

Comment: Best practices are to include code and output as *text* (in code format) rather than screenshots; screenshots are not searchable and are inaccessible to the visually impaired ... could you please edit your question accordingly?

Comment: also, `=` and `==` have different meanings, you might have a typo  (`data_sample = TRUE` and `data_sample == TRUE` are completely different)

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you, just a  typo. I'm an R noob and tend to use = instead of <- because it makes more sense to me logically.